# How to get a certificate out of Chrome now the padlock has gone?

Tags: certificate, google-chrome

I am used to clicking on the padlock in Chrome downloading the certificate and installing that in my jre.

Now the padlock has gone, I can not find how to download the certificate anymore.

Comment: I was torn between superuser and info security.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click the site information button in the URL bar:

[image: Connection is secure]

Click "Connection is secure", and then "Certificate is valid".

[image: Certificate viewer]

A dialog appears showing the certificate information. Switch to the "Details" tab. At the bottom is an "Export..." button.